# Socket.IO connection is not establishing

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

I am not able to establish the connection to Socket.IO in node server. My server is successfully started with Socket.IO but during the connection to Socket, I am not getting the console logs.

```
 this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on ${this.port} with process id ${process.pid}`)
    });

 this.io.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
        console.log(`Connected client on port ${this.port}`);

        socket.on('messsage', (msg: Message) => {
            console.log(`Data: ${msg}`);
            socket.emit('message', msg);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`Client Disconnected`);
        });
    });
```

Comment: share client code

Comment: <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chatmessage', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chatmessage', function (msg) {
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
  });
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your code:
`var socket = io.connect('localhost');`

to

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:port');`

Comment: replace port on which you are running node server

Comment: Yes, I tried and it is also working without giving port. But, now I am continuously getting a connection logs

Comment: what is your port ?

Comment: My Port is 4000

Comment: so now your connection is reseting?

Comment: Yes, on both side the port is same